# How to join columns in a pandas dataframe, with empty values, considering priority?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm doing a university job with a pandas dataframe, as below:

```
      import numpy as np
      import pandas as pd

      df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [np.NaN, 11.2, 10, np.NaN, 1000],
                         'sensor_name': ['water', 'strain', 'fog', 'water', 'fog'],
                         'col2': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 30, 40, np.NaN],
                         'col3': [np.NaN, 2, 30, 44, np.NaN]
                         })

      print(df)

      col1    sensor_name   col2    col3
      NaN      water         NaN    NaN
      11.2     strain        NaN    2.0
      10.0     fog           30.0   30.0
      NaN      water         40.0   44.0
      1000.0   fog           NaN    NaN
```

I would like to join columns 1, 2 and 3, to avoid the NaN values.
The priority would be the value in col1, if any. Then the priority would be 'col2' and finally 'col3'.

I tried to do the following code:

```
      df['new_column'] = df.ffill(axis=1)['col3']
```

The output is:

```
      col1     sensor_name      col2    col3    new_column
       NaN      water           NaN     NaN       water
       11.2     strain          NaN     2.0       2.0
       10.0     fog             30.0    30.0      30.0
       NaN      water           40.0    44.0      44.0
       NaN      fog             NaN     NaN       fog
```

However, the desired output is:

```
       col1    sensor_name      col2    col3    new_column
       NaN      water           NaN     NaN       NaN
       11.2     strain          NaN     2.0       11.2
       10.0     fog             30.0    30.0      10.0
       NaN      water           40.0    44.0      40.0
       1000.0   fog             NaN     NaN       1000.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many ways you can achieve is using `pandas.apply` function.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [np.NaN, 11.2, 10, np.NaN, 1000],
                         'sensor_name': ['water', 'strain', 'fog', 'water', 'fog'],
                         'col2': [np.NaN, np.NaN, 30, 40, np.NaN],
                         'col3': [np.NaN, 2, 30, 44, np.NaN]
                         })

print(df)

def apply_func(row):
  if not pd.isna(row['col1']):
    return row['col1']
  elif not pd.isna(row['col2']):
    return row['col2']
  return row["col3"]

df["new_cols"]=df.apply(apply_func,axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     col1 sensor_name  col2  col3  new_cols
0     NaN       water   NaN   NaN       NaN
1    11.2      strain   NaN   2.0      11.2
2    10.0         fog  30.0  30.0      10.0
3     NaN       water  40.0  44.0      40.0
4  1000.0         fog   NaN   NaN    1000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter the column

```
df['new'] = df.filter(like='col').bfill(1)['col1']
df
Out[324]: 
     col1 sensor_name  col2  col3     new
0     NaN       water   NaN   NaN     NaN
1    11.2      strain   NaN   2.0    11.2
2    10.0         fog  30.0  30.0    10.0
3     NaN       water  40.0  44.0    40.0
4  1000.0         fog   NaN   NaN  1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
f = df.filter(regex='col\d')
res = df.assign(new_column=f.where(f.notnull().cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)).max(axis=1))
print(res)
>>>
    col1    sensor_name col2    col3    new_column
0   NaN     water       NaN     NaN     NaN
1   11.2    strain      NaN     2.0     11.2
2   10.0    fog         30.0    30.0    10.0
3   NaN     water       40.0    44.0    40.0
4   1000.0  fog         NaN     NaN     1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['new_column'] = df['col1']
index = df[df['new_column'].isna()].index
df.iloc[index,4]= df.iloc[index,2]
index = df[df['new_column'].isna()].index
df.iloc[index,4]= df.iloc[index,3]
```

You could create a for loop if you had more columns to consider and/or wanted it to be more automated.